# Cloud scale user management

Tags: authentication, database-design, architecture, cloud, microservices

I am building a service to handle a large number of devices, for a large number of users.

We have a complex schema of access roles assigned to each entity. Some data entries can be written to by certain users, while some users can only read from some entities (but can write to others).

This is a cloud service: there are more devices, and users than can be handled by a single server machine (we are using non relational Cloud databases for this).

I was wondering if there was an established cloud-scale user/role management backend system which I could integrate to enforce the access rules, instead of writing my own. This tech should preferably be cloud agnostic, so I would prefer not to use a SAAS solution, but deploy my own.

I am looking for a system which can scale to millions of users, and billions of data entities

Answer (score 1):

I think authentication is not going to be a big issue, there are very robust cloud based solutions available for storing identities and authenticating millions of users. Authorization will be trickier, and will depend a lot on how granular you want it to be. You could look at Apigee for example as a very scalable proxy that might help you implement this. So getting to the point where you have a token that you can verify the users identity with and that might contain some scopes is not going to be hard imo. If that is enough for you then I would just look at Auth.0, Okta and the native IDM solution of whatever cloud platform you are using (Cognito, Cloud Identity etc.).

I think you will find that more features come with a very hefty pricetag. So Auth.0 is far superior compared to Cognito, but Cognito still has enough features for basic use cases and will end up costing a fraction of Auth.0 in large deployments. So everything comes with pros and cons. If you have very complex requirements such as a bunch of big legacy repositories that you need to integrate then products like Auth.0 rapidly start looking more attractive.

Personally I would look at Auth.0, Cognito and Apigee and my decision would depend massively on parameters that you haven't mentioned in your question. Obviously these are all SaaS solutions, which I think you should definitely be using anyways. I would not host this myself unless I had no other choice, and going that route will radically limit your choices and probably increase expenses. All the cool stuff is happening in the cloud.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I am not looking for authentication (as you mentioned, that's easy). I'm looking for fine-grained authorisation (many resources, with different roles, and different permissions). And no, it cannot be SAAS, because this project has private hosting requirements (as cool as the cloud is, I can't really use it). I do however have a bit of budget to spend on professional resources (if they're worth it). While I see that Okta supports some authorization, it looks like its only "role based" which might not have the resolution I need.

Comment: Ok, I am not up to date on middleware, but I would probably lean towards coding this myself if I had to. The problem is always going to be finding something that matches your requirements exactly, because if you end up customizing in any non-minor way you will be in for a world of hurt in the long run.